# Swapping boot and backup disks during WinPE's image restore procedure

Tags: windows-7, memory, backup, disk-image, ramdisk

I have 4Gb of DDR in a laptop running Windows 7.  I want to do a full Windows system image restore from a 2nd hard-drive that I use in the CD/DVD cartridge slot with a "drive caddy" adapter.   When doing a recovery, I want to boot from a standard CD/DVD read unit with a typical CD repair disk first (loading the WinPE/RE into a ramdisk), and then remove the standard CD/DVD unit from the laptop so that the caddy adapter w/hard-drive containing the backed-up image files can be inserted in place of the CD/DVD unit and recognized by WinRE. (CD boot media is preferred and seems more native and simpler than a USB boot type) I would like to know from other's experience if the loaded WinRE will be able to complete the image restoration from the 4Gb ramdisk without needing additional access to the CD repair disk during the restore procedure?     In other words, can WinPE run the entire image transfer within just 4Gb of RAM after a repair or installation CD is removed - leaving WinPE loaded in a RAMdisk as X:> ?